# Use the same name for 64 and 32 bit windbg extension

Tags: windbg

I have a WinDbg extension that works with both the 32-bit and 64-bit versions.  I would like to be able to use it by the same name in both versions.  I tried giving both extension dlls the same name in different directories and added both directories to my `_NT_DEBUGGER_EXTENSION_PATH`, but WinDbg will just attempt to load whichever one comes first, failling if it is the wrong bitness.

Is there a way to get each version of WinDbg to see its own version of the extension dll?

Comment: copy the DLL with the correct bitness to the **C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\ARCH\winext**

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you create WinDbg shortcuts and start each version with its own extension path, e.g.

```
windbg.exe -c ".extpath+ c:\path\to\bitness\"
```